# How do I locate an external device through terminal?

Tags: terminal, signal-processing

I am an intern at a company which built a speaker with an internal DSP chip which includes a microphone to record audio, as well as way to produce pink noise. We plug the speaker into a computer via a usb drive and we can extract the recorded audio onto the computer for desired research involving RT-60 measured with impulse response.

On my coworker's PC, he typed 'cmd -qY' into his shell interface and was able to access the speaker in order to extract the recorded audio files from the speaker. This code is a prompt through micropython and he was allowed to type in other code in order to register the speaker as an external hard-drive and then upload files from the speaker. I am having trouble getting this to work on my Mac, for when I type that prompt in Terminal my computer says "-bash: cmd: command not found." My computer is also not registering the speaker as an external device, which I believe to be the root of the problem, as well as my lack of knowledge regarding the difference between PC and Mac command interfaces.

Comment: What do you expect us to do? Explain all the differences, and why cmd is a Windows  thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by downloading CoolTerm, an application for Mac. I go to the options on CoolTerm and select the port that I want, which shows up as a USB when I have the speaker plugged in. From there, I go to Terminal in the options menu and click 'Line Mode' So I can type in code in CoolTerm. I go back to the main Cool Term interface and click connect. Then I enter in the line the desired prompts (which were written by my coworker and have no application outside this use) and wait a bit and then my speaker shows as an external hard-drive from which I can take files. I think the important lesson to draw from this is to bear in mind that CoolTerm is a very useful tool for external devices whose software were designed on a PC and may not be compatible with Mac and identified as external hard-drives. CoolTerm is a great application for this purpose and I recommend it to anyone having issues with viewing external devices on their computer.